# Why annotation @SuppressWarnings is used?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jvm, vaadin, vaadin7

Why the annotation is used: *@SuppressWarnings("serial")* in vaadin 7.0 applications with Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SuppressWarnings annotation is one of the three built-in annotations available in JDK and added alongside @Override and @Deprecated in Java 1.5. @SuppressWarnings instruct the compiler to ignore or suppress, specified compiler warning in annotated element and all program elements inside that element. For example, if a class is annotated to suppress a particular warning, then a warning generated in a method inside that class will also be separated. Hope this helps.

Comment: can you this as the answer then pls